# Linux Java Wrapper Service, NoClassDefFoundError caused by too many open files

Tags: java, linux

I set a java wrapper service in linux rc.local file.
when I reboot the system, then start 200 request per second, will rise exceptions like:
[image]

But if I stop the service and start manually, no exception happens.

I used `lsof | wc -l`, result count is not larger than 30000.

What may cause that problem?

Some linux config like:

```
[root@38 ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63674
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 655350
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63674
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

[root@38 ~]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr 
25632   0       1619324
[root@38 ~]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max 
1619324
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause.

The real limit to a process can be found by `cat /proc/[PID]/limits`

I can configure open files limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.conf`. I can see configured number by `ulimit -a` because I logined, we can find  limits.conf is config for the pam_limits module by "man",  for login session. But if start service in rc.local, pam_limits module will not effect.

Finally, I resolved this problem by adding `ulimit` command in rc.local:
`ulimit -SHn 655350`

Comment: I don't know is that a good solution. Are there some other ways?